# Using markdown for templates in Hakyll

Tags: haskell, pandoc, hakyll

Using the skeleton website generated by `hakyll-init site_foo`, I want to translate `site_foo/index.html` into markdown and still keep its contents.

In other words, have a `site_foo/index.markdown` that refers to the `posts-list` template.

I do not know which functions one would combine to achieve the correct `Compiler` for `match "index.markdown"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've already created your `index.markdown` file to replace `index.html` you can change `site.hs` to look like:

```
getResourceBody
    >>= applyAsTemplate indexCtx
    >>= return . renderPandoc
    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" indexCtx
    >>= relativizeUrls
```

The new line is the 3rd one, `>>= return . renderPandoc`.

The Pandoc compiler will render your HTML-based templates fine, however you may need to remove indentation from the HTML-based templates so Pandoc doesn't confuse the templates as code blocks.

I've used and tested this solution, but all credit for identifying the solutions is due to Jasper's answer in the Hakyll forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hakyll/ooMEwuiQZ24